# Join table-type object with a regular table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a regular table with entries and several types declared like that:

```
create TYPE entity as OBJECT ( attribute1 NUMBER);
create TYPE entity_array as OBJECT of entity;
```

And now I want using the sql worksheet join declared `entity_array` object with my table:

```
DECLARE
        entity_array_obj entity_array := entity_array(
          entity(11111),
          entity(22222)
          );
BEGIN
       select * from mytable as t1 
       inner join entity_array_obj as t2 on (t1.attribute1 = t2.attribute1);
END;
```

And I'm getting compilation error:

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create type entity as object ( attribute1 number);
create type entity_array as table of entity;

create table mytable(attribute1 number);
insert into mytable values (11111);

declare
    entity_array_obj entity_array := entity_array(
        entity(11111),
        entity(22222)
    );
    v_count number;
begin
    select count(*)
    into v_count
    from mytable t1
    join table(entity_array_obj) t2
        on t1.attribute1 = t2.attribute1;

    dbms_output.put_line('Count: '||v_count);
end;
/
```

Here are the main changes made to the code:

1. Changed `as OBJECT of entity;` to `as TABLE of entity;`.  You may not have noticed this error because some IDEs suppress code compilation errors.
2. Table aliasing in Oracle does not work with "as".
3. Selects in PL/SQL must always select INTO something.
4. The `table()` operator converts the collection into a row source.

Comment: the 3d item was the most important one for me! Tnx

Comment: which version of oracle are you using? I'm working on 10g and it does not work.

Comment: Never mind, It ws unrelated this, had to put a grant on one of the join table. erro was gone Thanks for replying.